# Is there a free API for generating Google compatible sitemaps?

Tags: api, sitemap

There's plenty of websites that offer this service for free, like [this one](http://www.xml-sitemaps.com/).

The input/output for the service is perfect. Here's a url, and it gives me back some XML.

Does anyone know of a similar service that is available as an API, so I can just call it by passing a site url, and it return some xml?

Comment: I have written this API [ https://www.codepunker.com/tools/sitemap-generator ] which might be of interest to people stumbling over this question.

Comment: Check out https://wutmap.com - I've been using them for about a year now and haven't had any issues.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not free. But you could use the command line version of A1 Sitemap Generator. It can do what you want, see: http://www.microsystools.com/products/sitemap-generator/help/automate-sitemap-build-upload/

Otherwise, I believe you can find some old PHP scripts that create sitemaps, and then maybe tailor them to your needs? One example might be: http://enarion.net/tools/phpsitemapng/